# CreateObject with method and params dynamical through string

Tags: vb.net

I have an object with a class name such as
MyObjName.MyClassName and MyClassName contains a method called CalculateSum which accepts two parameters (string a, boolean b)

Calling that object through code is quite easy but I need to call it by passing it as strings

i.e How to set this : object

```
Dim fullObjName As String = "MyObjName.MyClassName"
Dim methodName As String = "CalculateSUM"
Dim param1 As String = "a"
Dim param2 As Boolean = True
```

I tried with:

```
Public Shared Function InvokeStringMethod2(ByVal typeName As String, ByVal methodName As String, ByVal stringParam As String, boolparam As Boolean) As String
    Dim calledType As Type = Type.[GetType](typeName)
    Dim s As String = CType(calledType.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod Or BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.[Static], Nothing, Nothing, New Object() {stringParam, boolparam}), String)
    Return s
End Function
```

Comment: It might be easier using the built-in VB function 'CallByName'.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas thanks for fast answer. I need to mention sometimes i need to call two methods in same object without setting it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from Dave made my work

```
Dim obj As New Object
obj = CreateObject("MyObjName.MyClassName")
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallByName(obj, "CalculateSUM", CallType.Method, "a", True)
```

In case you need to call another method in same object you can use

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallByName(obj, "Show_Form", CallType.Method)
```